# How to force a user to enter only numeric values in an edit text?

Tags: android

i am developing a restaurant mobile application,and i have an edittext that will receive numeric value only..i have to prevent the user from adding string values.

Any suggestions i would highly appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

Add `android:inputType="number"` to your EditText.

[Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: *used **to help** an input method decide how to let the user enter text* ... you see *to help* not *to force* ... with some custom keyboard it would be easy to put non number ... or with paste

Comment: ok thanks a lot it worked but under edittext i have a button
how to prevent the user from pressing the button if edittext is empty?

Comment: @Selvin: I am not sure about custom keyboard, but paste does not work. It doesn't paste any non number character with `inputType` set.

Comment: @MahdiHr: That's a completely different question. Ask a new question.